# If..else not working in Oracle

Tags: oracle, if-statement, stored-procedures, plsql

I have written a procedure containing a simple if..else if..end if as below.
While compiling it throws an error as

> Error(103,8): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LOOP" when expecting one of the following:     if 
>   Error(113,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static    member constructor map

I am unable to find the cause of error as I assume that I have closed all the IFs correctly. Can anyone pls help. Below is my whole procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_ntitems_update
AS
   CURSOR cur_systeminfo
   IS
      SELECT location,
             childseq,
             btproduct,
             product,
             questionid
        FROM systeminfo;

   vproduct         tblsysteminfo_products.product%TYPE;
   vquestionid      tblsysteminfo_products.questionid%TYPE;
   vlocation        systeminfo.location%TYPE;
   vchildseq        systeminfo.childseq%TYPE;
   verror           VARCHAR2 (200);
   consrgsitename   VARCHAR2 (100);
   consrgsite       VARCHAR2 (100);
   conmgsitename    VARCHAR2 (100);
   intname          NUMBER;
   vsicount         NUMBER;
BEGIN
   OPEN cur_systeminfo;

   LOOP
      FETCH cur_systeminfo
      INTO vlocation, vchildseq, vbtproduct, vproduct, vquestionid;

      EXIT WHEN cur_systeminfo%NOTFOUND;

      IF INSTR (vlocation, '_') > 0
      THEN
         vquestionid := consrgsitename;

         IF SUBSTR (vlocation, 1, LENGTH (consrgsite)) = consrgsite
         THEN
            intname := LENGTH (consrgsite);
            vquestionid := consrgsitename;
         ELSE
            IF SUBSTR (vlocation, 1, LENGTH (consrg50site)) = consrg50site
            THEN
               intname := LENGTH (consrgsite);
               vquestionid := consrgsitename;
               vlocation :=
                     vlocation
                  || SUBSTR (vlocation, intname + 1, LENGTH (vlocation));
            --Check if this item is for a DATA site. These have a Location of locations_data_n where n is  the site number.

            ELSE
               IF LOWER (SUBSTR (vlocation, 1, 14)) = 'locations_data'
               THEN
                  vsitename := 'Yes';
                  vquestionid := 'txtLocationName';
               ELSE
                  IF     LOWER (SUBSTR (vlocation, 1, 14)) = 'locations_data'
                     AND vchildseq = '0'
                  THEN
                     BEGIN
                        SELECT COUNT (location)
                          INTO vsicount
                          FROM systeminfo
                         WHERE LOWER (vlocation) = 'locations_1';
                     EXCEPTION
                        WHEN nodatafound
                        THEN
                           verror :=
                                 ' proc_ntitems_update '
                              || SUBSTR (
                                    TO_CHAR (SQLCODE) || ' - ' || SQLERRM,
                                    1,
                                    480);
                        WHEN OTHERS
                        THEN
                           verror :=
                                 ' proc_ntitems_update '
                              || SUBSTR (
                                    TO_CHAR (SQLCODE) || ' - ' || SQLERRM,
                                    1,
                                    480);
                     END;

                     IF vsicount = 0
                     THEN
                        vsitename := 'No';
                        intname := LENGTH (vlocation);
                        vquestionid := 'txtLocationName';
                     END IF;
                  ELSE
                     IF     LOWER (SUBSTR (vlocation, 1, 14)) =
                               'locations_data'
                        AND vchildseq > '0'
                     THEN
                        vquestionid := 'txtLocationName';
                     ELSE
                        IF LOWER (SUBSTR (vlocation, 1, 5)) = 'ripe_'
                        THEN
                           vremotesitenumber :=
                              SUBSTR (
                                 vlocation,
                                 -1,
                                 (LENGTH (vloaction) - INSTR (vlocation, '_')));
                           vproduct := 'MMRemote';
                           vquestionid := 'cboRemoteType' || vremotesitenumber;
                           vsitename := vecvalue || ' ' || vremotesitenumber;
                        ELSE
                           IF LOWER (
                                 SUBSTR (vlocation,
                                         1,
                                         LENGTH (conmerchandisesite))) =
                                 conmerchandisesite
                           THEN
                              vsitename := conmerchandisesite;
                           ELSE
                              vsitename := btproduct;
                           END IF;


                           BEGIN
                              UPDATE tblntitems
                                 SET location = vlocation,
                                     childseq = vchildseq,
                                     sitename = vbtproduct,
                                     product = vproduct,
                                     questionid = vquestionid
                               WHERE questionid = vquestionid;
                           EXCEPTION
                              WHEN OTHERS
                              THEN
                                 verror :=
                                       'proc_ntitems_update '
                                    || SUBSTR (
                                             TO_CHAR (SQLCODE)
                                          || ' - '
                                          || SQLERRM,
                                          1,
                                          480);
                           END;
                        END IF;
                     END loop;

   CLOSE   cur_systeminfo;

      EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS
        THEN
              verror := 'proc_ntitems_update ' || substr (to_char (sqlcode) || ' - ' || sqlerrm, 1, 480);

        INSERT INTO log_import_errors VALUES ('sysdate', verror);
END;
```

Comment: In PL/SQL we use `elsif` not `else if` for this kind of logic.  You can use `else if` but then you are starting a new `if` block and need an `end if` for each instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating nested if-then-else statements; you have the `ELSE` and `IF` on the same line but they are separate levels of control. It might be easier to understand where you're going wrong if arranged with indentation to show the nesting, as:

```
LOOP
  ...
  IF Instr(Vlocation,'_') >0 THEN
    ...
    IF SUBSTR(Vlocation,1,LENGTH(Consrgsite)) = Consrgsite THEN
      ...
    ELSE
      IF SUBSTR(Vlocation,1,LENGTH(Consrg50site)) = Consrg50site THEN
        ...
      ELSE
        IF Lower(SUBSTR(Vlocation,1,14)) = 'locations_data' THEN
          ...
        ELSE
          IF Lower(SUBSTR(Vlocation,1,14)) = 'locations_data' AND Vchildseq = '0' THEN
            ...
            IF Vsicount = 0 THEN
              ...
            END IF;
          ELSE
            IF Lower(SUBSTR(Vlocation,1,14)) = 'locations_data' AND Vchildseq > '0' THEN
              ...
            ELSE
              IF Lower(SUBSTR(Vlocation,1,5)) = 'ripe_' THEN
                ...
              ELSE
                IF Lower(SUBSTR(Vlocation,1,LENGTH(Conmerchandisesite))) = Conmerchandisesite THEN
                  ...
                ELSE
                  ...
                END IF;
                ...
              END IF;
            END LOOP;
```

Where you currently have `END LOOP` it's expecting to see `END IF`, which would match the `IF Lower(SUBSTR(Vlocation,1,14)) = 'locations_data' AND Vchildseq > '0' THEN` line.

As Tony Andrews said in a comment you need to have an `END IF` to match every `IF`. You currently have six levels of control that are opened with `IF` but not closed with `END IF`.

You seem to be expecting it to work like [`ELSIF`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS391), which you can use instead:

```
LOOP
  ...
  IF Instr(Vlocation,'_') >0 THEN
    ...
    IF SUBSTR(Vlocation,1,LENGTH(Consrgsite)) = Consrgsite THEN
      ...
    ELSIF SUBSTR(Vlocation,1,LENGTH(Consrg50site)) = Consrg50site THEN
      ...
    ELSIF Lower(SUBSTR(Vlocation,1,14)) = 'locations_data' THEN
      ...
    ELSIF Lower(SUBSTR(Vlocation,1,14)) = 'locations_data' AND Vchildseq = '0' THEN
      ...
      IF Vsicount = 0 THEN
        ...
      END IF;
    ELSIF Lower(SUBSTR(Vlocation,1,14)) = 'locations_data' AND Vchildseq > '0' THEN
      ...
    ELSIF Lower(SUBSTR(Vlocation,1,5)) = 'ripe_' THEN
      ...
    ELSIF Lower(SUBSTR(Vlocation,1,LENGTH(Conmerchandisesite))) = Conmerchandisesite THEN
      ...
    ELSE
      ...
    END IF;
  ...
  END IF;
END LOOP;
```

You could also use a [searched `CASE` expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS99972) instead of if-then-elsif-else, but the effect if the same.

Read more about [conditional control statements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS00402).